# A container to store a lot of elements

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

all!

I am trying to load in memory a set of files. for each file, around 10000 entries are loaded.
it should be totaly possible to hold the whole information is memory (i calculated the size in Mb, should fit), however, at some point I always get bad_alloc exception from the vector where i try to store the entries.

First question is, what is the limit of memory that can be allocated using vector? the number of elements that are allocated before the exception is not even close to the max_size()

Second question is, which kind of structure in stl or boost can I use to load the whole set in memory?

I am greatfull for any help!

Comment: The actual code would be much more informative than your description of said-same.

Comment: Please consider that the size of the whole structure is memory can be larger than the size in bytes of the file you are reading.

Comment: Is this a 32 bit application? Remember on windows regardless of the ram you have your address space will be limited to 2GB unless you use the LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker setting and on top of that you may run into address space fragmentation due to the locations your code and dlls load in your address space.

Comment: This might be a case where mmap() is more useful than the traditional read-the-file-into-a-data-structure approach.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what your code actually does and what environment you're running this on, one thing is certain: `std::vector` allocates continuous storage. This means that due to address space (memory?) fragmentation you will get this result, because there is just no room to allocate everything *continuously*.

If you see that this is happening, either use a non-continuous container (like `std::list`) or make sure you only load chunks into memory at a time, not the whole thing.

Comment: Fragmentation can be reduced by telling `std::vector` the maximum size at declaration.

Comment: It will not prevent previous fragmentation of the total address space, which may or may not be as dramatic as I make it sound depending on the OS.